# Android how to open same activity with different relative layout views when onclick buttons?

Tags: android

Sorry for my very bad english..my question is i have 2 activities..for example Activity A and Activity B,in Activity B UI i have 3 Relative Layouts which id's is rl_main(parent layout),
rl_A and rl_B .i have 2 buttons on Activity A which name is btnA and btnB..now my point is that,when i click on btnA Activity B is called,but the rl_A is visible for the btnA and rl_B is invisible,and when click on btnB the same Activity B is called,and this time the rl_A is invisible and rl_B is visible.any help will be much appreciated..Thank Alot in Advance.and also this is my first post question :) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a flag value by intent.

In Activity A:

**Button A Clicked:**

```
 Intent i=new Intent(Activity_A.this,Activity_B.class);
 i.putExtra("btn",1);
 startActivity(i);
```

**Button B Clicked:**

```
 Intent i=new Intent(Activity_A.this,Activity_B.class);
 i.putExtra("btn",2);
 startActivity(i);
```

**In Activity B onCreate:**

```
int i=getIntent().getIntExtra("btn");
if(i==1)
{
rl_A.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
rl_B.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else
if(i==2)
{
rl_A.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);
rl_B.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: it's Awwwsommmee Dude Thanks Alot..its working fine again Bundle of thanks :) and sorry i am new user so i does't use my vote to up ur ans until i have 20reputations..